# Angualr HTTP post subscribe is not worning and display in network tag

Tags: angular

I'm trying to http post request to api, subscribe is not working and not show request in broweser network tag.

here is login.component.ts code.

```
onloginFormSubmit(form){
    if(!form.valid){
     toastr.error('Please provide valid data!');
      return false;
    }

   var check =  this.adminAuth.login(this.admin).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
       console.log('ok');
        toastr.success(res.message);
        this.adminAuth.saveUser(res.user,res.token);
        window.location.href = "#/dashboard";
      },    
    (res:any)=>{
      if(res.error){        
        toastr.error(res.error.message);
      }
    });

    console.log(check);

  }
```

here is auth.service.ts code

```
login(data){
    let url = API_URL+"/admin/login";    
    return this.http.post(url, data, httpOptions);
  }
```

here is check variable result 
[image]

Comment: try putting console.log(res); inside the subscribe() to see if there's any response. 'check' will only log the observable stream.Also check if the api is working using postman or something

Comment: now console.log('ok') is not appear in console tag. So console.log(res) also will not show. thank. Api is working well with postman .

Comment: dont assign subscription to variable, instead go direct

Comment: `this.adminAuth.login(this.admin).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
       console.log('ok');
        toastr.success(res.message);
        this.adminAuth.saveUser(res.user,res.token);
        window.location.href = "#/dashboard";
      },    
    (res:any)=>{
      if(res.error){        
        toastr.error(res.error.message);
      }
    });`

Comment: thank but still same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Now, I got solution by removing httpOptions in post request. but I don't know it is good practice or not.